# window.addEventListener is listening to window.parent.postMessage twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, postmessage

When certain button is being clicked from child Iframe this function is being fired:

```
function someFunc(e) {
    some Code
    window.parent.postMessage(
        {
            event_id: 'id_id',
            data: {
                note: note
            }
        },
        "*"
    );
}
```

In Parent Window it's being listened

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (event.data.event_id === 'id_id') {
        var note = event.data.data.note;
        do something with note
    }
},false);
```

The problem here is for one click someFunc() function is being called once but somehow window.addEventListener listener is listening to it twice. Can't find why it's behaving in such way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my Angular 8 app.
The only way I got rid of these multiple messages between the listener and the iFrame was to add this code to my component:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {    
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.messageHandler, false);
  }
```

This leads to the conclusion that there are not multiple messages, **but** multiple listeners.